# How to apply multiple case conditions on a single parameter in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have the following (shortened) code:

```
WHERE
analysis.debtor.gender=CASE
WHEN ?='Men' THEN 'MALE'
ELSE 'FEMALE'
END
```

This works but I would like to have multiple cases for the same parameter, ?, ie.

```
WHEN ?='Men' THEN 'MALE', WHEN ?='Female' THEN Female ELSE
```

it should include both men and woman. 
How can I implement this in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `OR` to add another condition:

```
WHERE
    analysis.debtor.gender=CASE WHEN ?='Men' THEN 'MALE' ELSE 'FEMALE' END OR
    (? NOT IN ('Men', 'Female'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a case statement as

```
CASE COLUMN_NAME
WHEN 'Men' THEN 'MALE'
WHEN 'Female' THEN 'FEMALE'
ELSE 'MEN AND WOMEN'
END
```

If you provide your complete query, will be useful to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you have only exact equality conditions, then you can do:

```
WHERE analysis.debtor.gender = (CASE ? WHEN 'Men' THEN 'MALE' WHEN 'Women' THEN 'FEMALE' END)
```

I'm not a big fan of putting `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause.  It can be hard to maintain.  An alternative is to use a `params` subquery:

```
FROM (SELECT ? as val) params CROSS JOIN
     . . .
WHERE (analysis.debtor.gender = 'MALE' and val = 'Men') OR
      (analysis.debtor.gender = 'FEMALE' and val = 'Women')
```

Answer (score 0):

you was almost right with your sintax, you can write it also this way

```
WHERE analysis.debtor.gender = 
    case 
        when ?='Men' then 'MALE' 
        when ?='Female' then 'FEMALE' 
        when ?='Cross' then 'XGENDER' 
        else 'UNKNOWN' 
    end
```